# redirect с регулярным выражением htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Здравствуйте.
Я не силен в регулярных выражениях в htaccess-е.
Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно написать редирект на страницу 404.
Я пробовал такой код

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category/ ^+d [NC] 
RewriteRule domains.ru/404 [R=301,L]
```

мне надо, что бы перенаправлялись все url которые после category/ начинаются цифрами

пример - domains.ru / category / *456465*  => domains.ru / 404

За ранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал редирект таким способом:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule category/\d 404 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Одной командой попробуйте

```
# включаем mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# отлавливаем проблемные страницы и возвращаем 404 ошибку
RewriteRule category/\d - [L,R=404]
```

Если папка `category` в корне сайта, то можно так

```
RewriteRule ^category/\d - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: написал так "RewriteRule domeins.ru/categiry/\d - [L,R=404]", но редирект не делает. category не в корне.

Comment: @Taron, не надо домен дописывать в условие, он там не обрабатывается из-за его отсутствия. Используйте первый вариант из моего ответа. Хотя из `пример - domains.ru / category / 456465` папка `category` у вас в корне домена находится.

Comment: я и так написал RewriteRule category/\d - [L,R=404], но редирект не делает.

Comment: может это из за того что до него написан такой код RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: @Taron, да. Команда `RewriteRule category/\d - [L,R=404]` должна стоять сразу после `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: все равно не пашет, может пробовать RedirectMatch-ом ?

Comment: @Taron, поставьте такую команду `RewriteRule category/\d - [L,F]`. Запрет доступа по необходимым url появится? Какая версия апача у вас установлена? P.S. Раз у вас все страницы открываются через index.php, то лучше бы всю логику писать на php в роутере, а не мучатся с правилами в .htaccess.

Comment: Так тоже не работает, выдает проблему с сервером (500). Большое спасибо, решил проблему редиректом 301. Вы мне очень помогли, Спасибо.